# Comparing three vectors in R

Tags: r

I have three vectors of length 1000, I'm trying to compute the fraction of elements in which vector1 < vector2 < vector3. Usually I can just run the mean(v1 < v2 < v3) but R doesnt support that, so I did mean ((v1 < v2) & (v2 < v3)) but this is giving me nonsensical answers. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example? Seems like `mean ((v1 < v2) & (v2 < v3))` should work. (Of course the example does not need to be 1000 long)

Comment: x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(2,-1,8,3)
z = c(3,9,-15,5)
print(mean((x <y) &&(y < z)))

Comment: Basically what seems to be happening is it returns 1 if such an example exists and 0 if it doesnt, which is not what I intend... I want the fraction of which x < y <z

Comment: You lied to us. Using `&&` is NOT the same as using `&`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Lied is a strong term, but yeah, this is exactly why reproducible examples are helpful. For details on & vs &&, see `?base::Logic`.